# how to make first in first out when received the data

Tags: go

So, I want to make these lines of code can return the value as first in first out, I was trying to do that but it's only read the last input for the first output

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        scanner.Scan()
        input := scanner.Text()
        if input == "" {
            break
        }
        defer fmt.Println(input)
    }
}
```

```
$ go run main.go
1
2
3

3
2
1
```

Comment: Make your `[]string` and save your inputs there.

Comment: Don't use `defer`. Deferred functions are executed LIFO and you want FIFO, so simply gather the inputs in a slice, and print them in order after the loop (using another loop).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of string slice

```
func main() {
    var (
        scanner = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        output  []string
    )
    for {
        scanner.Scan()
        input := scanner.Text()
        if input == "" {
            break
        }
        output = append(output, input)
    }
    for _, val := range output {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).